# RoR facebox for prototype

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got facebox working using the following tags in my rails app

```
<%= link_to 'test' some_path, :rel => 'facebox' %>
```

Now that works perfect if the page is already loaded.

However, I have ajax updates on certain parts of the page which contain new links like the one shown above.

When you click the links from an ajax update facebox doesn't work follows on to the template.

I believe since the page doesn't refresh the source code is the same and :rel => 'facebox' doesn't work.

Does anyone have any advice on how I can get this to work without refreshing the page?

I've tried this in a method in a controller.

```
render :update do |page|
  page << "
    facebox.loading();
    facebox.reveal('text', null); 
    new Effect.Appear(facebox.facebox, {duration: .3});     
  "  
end
```

However, for some reason in chrome and IE the facebox appears for a brief second and then disappears.

Any advice?  I've been banging my head off the wall all day.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do, is ensure that you're making a javascript call to facebox somewhere in the view of your AJAX response: arguably the best location would be in the layout file. Just make sure that you include the following:

```
#app/views/layouts/ajax.html.erb
#...snip...

<% javascript_tag :defer => 'defer' do -%>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();
  })
<% end -%>
```

or with prototype (untested):

```
#app/views/layouts/ajax.html.erb
#...snip...

<% javascript_tag :defer => 'defer' do -%>
  document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    $$('a[rel*="facebox"]').facebox();
  });
<% end -%>
```

This will ensure that any new links that appear on the page, as part your AJAX updates, will be handled by facebox.

Comment: I've added a prototype solution to the answer, it should work ok - but I rarely use prototype, so i'm not 100% sure.

Comment: yeah not sure why but it doesn't work. I'm using link_to_remote to update a division on my page with a partial.  I add the prototype code to my template..

Comment: Make sure you added the prototype code to your layout that's used in your AJAX response (not default page layout).

Also, check to make sure that javascript block is appearing in the AJAX response (using firebug, or developer tools of your choice).

Finally, you could always try removing the event handler - and just using the $$('a[rel*="facebox"]').facebox(); line - in case for some reason, it's not firing.